# How is residual sum of squares derived from a given sample correlation coefficient and sample variance?

Tags: regression, self-study

How would one calculate the residual sum of squares when given the other values (r, n, sample means of x and y, and both sample variances), but not the dataset? x is the predictor, y is the response.

Edit: Found the formula. It's RSS=(1-r^2)*((n-1)*(var.y))

Answer (score 0):

The formula is RSS=$(1-r^2)((n-1)(\text{Var}[y]))$